# Why did the authors of psql decide to have capital U (`-U`) for the user option rather than small u (`-u`)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It makes so much more sense to just use the small u `-u` option for the user option. All other connection options (`-h`, `-p`, `-d`) are lowercase. `sudo` command also uses lowercase `-u` for its user option. The lowercase `-u` option is not used for anything else either.

Then why?

Comment: Most likeyl some historical reason.

Comment: And the historical reason could be that it confirms with `quel`s options. BTW: postgres predates sudo.

Comment: postgres doesn't predate sudo. sudo's initial release was 1980, postgres' development started in 1986 ([source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/history.html))

Comment: I stand corrected. Didn't know that sudo stems from BSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here from Postgres v7.0.0 [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.0/app-psql.htm). There was:

> -u

> Makes psql prompt for the user name and password before connecting to the database.

> This option is deprecated, as it is conceptually flawed.  (Prompting for a non-default user name and prompting for a password because the backend requires it are really two different things.) You are encouraged to look at the -U and -W options instead.

`psql` tries to maintain backwards compatibility going back a long ways. The `-u` option does not disappear until version 8.3. **Notes** for current version [psql current](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) refer to going back to version 7.4.